# Splitting String in C procudes Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, char, strsep

I'm trying to read from the keyboard something like a command
e.g.
`start game,info1,info2`
and I want to split and save those two strings, one having to do with what kind of command the user,types in and the other having information about the command.
I have done this so far, which reads and prints the separated by space strings but after that it hits me with this `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` and the console program stops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *command;
    char *value;
} string;

string *allocate_memory();
void split_command(char* cmd_info, string **s);

int main(void) {
    char cmd[255];
    memset(cmd, 0, 255);
    do
    {
        // read command
        fgets(cmd, 255, stdin);
        cmd[strcspn ( cmd, "\n")] = '\0';

        string *str;
        str = allocate_memory();
        split_command(cmd, &str);

        puts(str->command);
        puts(str->value);

        if(!strcmp(str->command, "start"))
            printf("Starting...\n");

    } while(strcmp(cmd, "exit"));
    printf("Exiting the command line.");
    return 0;
}

string *allocate_memory() {
  string *p;
  if( (p = (string *) malloc(sizeof(string))) == NULL ) {
    printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  return p;
}

void split_command(char* cmd_info, string **s) {

    string *new;
    new = allocate_memory();
    char *token;
    while ((token = strsep(&cmd_info, " ")) != NULL)
    {
      printf("%s\n", token);
      new->command = strdup(token);
    }
    new->value = strdup(token);
    puts(new->value);
    *s = new;
    free(cmd_info);

}
```

Compile

```
gcc cmd.c -o cmd.out
```

Output

```
./cmd.out 
one two
one
two
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've tried other stuff as well but I'm keep getting the Segmentation fault, I'm really stuck.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: thanks for the comment, just removed that, although same issue. By the way where did the other answer go?

Comment: Well I expect to have only one space, so it's executed only once. If the token is null how does it print correctly the values?

Comment: indeed it does print it twice. Thanks a lot user3121023 !!!

Answer (score 1):

`strsep()` sets token to `NULL` when no other delimiter is found. That `NULL` is then 
passed to `strdup()`, causing your the segmentation fault.

I removed the `while()` in `split_command()` (I assumed that it is a simple `command arg`)
and added a check before the second `strdup()` and got it working. I also fixed some memory leaks:

- you were allocating `str` in `main()` and then overriding it with `new` in 
  `split_command()` losing the reference to `str`.
- you were allocating a new string every loop iteration without freeing the previous one
- you weren't freeing the strings created using `strdup()`

Moreover, you were freeing `cmd_info` which is a buffer allocated statically on the stack.

This is my version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *command;
    char *value;
} string;

string *allocate_memory();
void split_command(char* cmd_info, string *s);

int main(void) {
    char cmd[255];
    string *str = allocate_memory();
    memset(cmd, 0, 255);
    do {
        fgets(cmd, 255, stdin);
        cmd[strcspn(cmd, "\n")] = '\0';

        split_command(cmd, str);

        if(!strcmp(str->command, "start"))
            printf("Starting...\n");

        free(str->command);
        free(str->value);
    } while(strcmp(cmd, "exit"));
    free(str);
    printf("Exiting the command line.");
    return 0;
}

string *allocate_memory() {
    string *p;
    if( (p = (string *) malloc(sizeof(string))) == NULL ) {
    printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
    exit(1);
    }
    return p;
}

void split_command(char* cmd_info, string *s) {
    char *token = strsep(&cmd_info, " ");

    s->command = strdup(token);
    token = strsep(&cmd_info, " ");
    if (token)
        s->value = strdup(token);
    else
        s->value = NULL;
}
```

Remember that passing `NULL` to `puts()` and such leads to problems: always check for `NULL`!

Answer (score 1):

I gave a try, But If your input string more than two spaces, You should definitely modify this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *command;
    char *value;
} string;
string *split_command(char *cmd);

int main()
{
    char cmd[255];
    while (1)
    {
        fgets(cmd, 255, stdin);
        if (!strcmp(cmd, "exit\n"))
        {
            break;
        }
        cmd[strcspn(cmd, "\n")] = '\0';

        string *str = split_command(cmd);
        puts(str->command);
        puts(str->value);
    }
    return 0;
}

string *split_command(char *cmd)
{
    string *new_string = (string *)malloc(sizeof(string));
    if(new_string == NULL) {
        printf("MEMORY_ALLOCATION_FAILED\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    char *token = strtok(cmd, " ");
    new_string->command = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    new_string->value = token;
    return new_string;
}
```